# Raw HTML to Image Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react component that is outputting a raw html string that I want to use to generate an image. This is different from most proposed solutions that I've seen that require either rendering this html to canvas and then capturing the canvas. I can turn that raw html into a document with jsPDF which I was going to use in memory to extract the image. I know this is a less than optimal solution. Basically I want to go from raw html to png ideally.

```
  exportHtml = () => {
    this.editor.exportHtml((data) => {

      const { design, myHtml } = data;

      var doc = new jsPDF("landscape", "pt", "A4");

      //Rather than outputting a pdf here this is where I'd expect to have an image in memory to save or pass
      doc.html(myHtml, {
        callback: () => {
          //This is where we would send the png'd pdf off to our storage
          doc.save("test.pdf");
        },
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Have a look at this NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image

Comment: That uses DOM as well. Will try plugging the html string into it and see what happens.